# Are there UIImageView differences between 4.2 and 4.3?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uiimageview, uiimage

I am pulling down some images and saving them to disk. Then dishing them out via UIImageView.

All works well in simulator under 4.2, but as soon as I switch it over to 4.3 all of the images are displayed inverted (they are xrays.. the black & white is reversed)

Any suggestions? I am just using

```
UIImageView *seriesImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathToImage]];
```

It works fine on 4.2, but not 4.3

any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: There are differences in the implementation, but they are unrelated to the issue you're having.  The problem is most likely on your side of things.

Comment: I'm just not sure what then. Switching between 4.2/4.3 in the simulator brings up two different results.. odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be shocked if there was any noticeable change in how `UIImageView` renders images between OS versions. The simulator isn't always totally reliable, so I'd recommend testing your code on a device running iOS 4.3.

Comment: Same thing happens when it is run /on/ the device. I can browse the directory contents and can see that the images are downloading correctly.. they are just inverted.

Comment: It's a bug in something. Compiles and runs fine from another machine.. *shrug*